# get list of all users from User profiles in SharePoint using REST API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, user-profile

I am able to get the list of site users by making a call to

```
site/_api/web/siteusers
```

I am able to get details of logged in user by visiting

```
site/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetMyProperties
```

I want to get the list of users from the user profiles

How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no client side way to iterate through user profiles. You can do through server side, [Reference Here](http://anthony-verschraegen.blogspot.in/2014/12/sharepoint-c-loop-through-user-profiles.html)

Now if you must do it through client side, there is a workaround. if your User profile data is perfectly managed and all users have the proper hierarchy, what you can do is start with company CEO / Top level employee. Get all his/her direct reports

> _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(**accountName**) + "'&$select=DirectReports"

Once you get direct reportees to top level/CEO , iterate through these users to get their direct reportees , you can keep looping til you get zero direct reprotees. This hould cover all the employees from Org.

**Warning**:

1. This will skip the user profiles which doesnt have any manager set against them.
2. Depending on how many profile you have this can take too long to run as you have to query against each account name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function RetrieveGroupUsers() {
    $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(8)/users?$select=ID,Title,Email,LoginName",
        type: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            var binding = "";

            if (data.d.results) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                    var id = data.d.results[i].ID;
                    var loginname = data.d.results[i].LoginName;
                    var title = data.d.results[i].Title;
                    var email = data.d.results[i].Email;
```

Comment: This is good , however, FYI..This will give only users who have visited to the site that you are referring above. This wont have all the user profiles.