# Get the collection of All User Profiles with REST API

Tags: rest, user-profile, jsom

I want to fetch all user profiles with Rest API,

If I did this with the SSOM - it takes a lot of time because the users are near about 7000 or more and I have to show them on search.

**E.g =>If I have searched with A then result should show all the users whose Last Name start with letter A**.

I got some references, [Link1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192096/get-list-of-all-users-from-user-profiles-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api), But this not worked for me!

Comment: Do you work with @AkshayDattatrayNangare ? Just curios

Comment: How did you guess? Because of Duplicate Question or The Kind of same question/ Requirement?

Comment: Your colleague answered several related questions around user profiles, some of them looks extremely similar to your.